# Laravel 5 how to run tests in a different database the right way?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm on 5.1 and not able to find a definite answer what's the best practice regarding an eco- and test-system to use a separate database for tests.

I've:

- a development machine for dev and running local tests
- an external service running by CI (only runs phpunit)

When I run tests locally, I don't want them to interfere with my dev database, thus I've created dedicated database for tests.

To overcome the limitation that I've only one `.env` file, I've modified the `phpunit.xml.dist` file to have different database credentials defined via `<env name="..." value=".."/>`.

When I want to run the tests on a remote CI service, I again need different values for user/pass and database names. In that case I've a "template phpunit.xml" file in my repo which, during the initialization phase on the remote CI, I generate with their respective environment variables (which are different than the ones I use).

For all non-production related environments I need to keep three files in sync otherwise things will start to break:

- `.env`
- `phpunit.xml.dist`
- `phpunit.xml` template file generated on demand on remote CI system

I understand the benefits of the non-versioned `.env`, but it gets a huge pain to always keep those things in sync.

Are there better ways to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I generated a `phpunit.xml` (note: no `.dist`!) in the CI environment with the special `<env>` variables pre-populated with a custom bash script.

I also found https://mattstauffer.co/blog/environment-specific-variables-in-laravels-testing-environment recently but didn't implement it.